# Почему регулярное выражение не срабатывает?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть огромный текст после парсинга и надо из него выдергивать вот такие строки:

```
"post_author_id":"459983269"
```

При этом надо учитывать что до этой строки еще куча текста и после нее.

```
$regexp = '/^\"post_author_id\":\"\d\"$/';
echo preg_match($regexp, '"post_author_id":"459983269"');
```

Результат выполнения кода выше = 0, а по идее должно быть 1, но видимо я что-то неправильно написал. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Если это JSON, используйте JSON-парсер. А ошибка простая: `\d` находит только одну цифру. Используйте что-то вроде `$regexp = '/"post_author_id":"(\d+)"/'`.

Comment: Забыли квантификатор звездочку `\d*` или плюс `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

регexp

```
("post_author_id":"\d*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regexp = '/^\"post_author_id\":\"\d*\"$/';
echo preg_match($regexp, '"post_author_id":"459983269"'); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых вам надо найти много строк, поэтому используйте функцию preg_match_all
Во вторых погуглите модификатор запроса те что пишутся в конце после ограничивающего слэша: U, i, s
На память не помню но вроде U как раз и позволяет искать в многострочном тексте, иначе любой перевод строки и ваш ограничитель в виде знака доллара в конце запроса останавливает поиск.
И последнее, если ваша строка которую вы ищете на стоит в самом начале строки, а перед ней может быть любой символ, уберите домик: ^ из начала запроса.